# Reversing colorbar without reversing a text

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, colorbar

I want to reverse a `colorbar`'s direction, and according to my search, setting `xdir` property to `reverse` is supposed to accomplish that. Turns out it does that and then, in MATLAB R2014a, flips all the text before and after as well a la Leonardo da Vinci! How can I stop this madness?

Example:

```
figure
subplot 311
plot(1:10)
set(gca,'xdir','reverse')
pause % ok up until here

subplot 312
surf(peaks)
colorbar('NorthOutside','xdir','reverse');

subplot 313
set(gca,'xdir','normal')
plot(1:10)
```

Thankfully, the text is flipped back to normal when the figure is exported or copied and pasted, but *not when it is saved as a MATLAB figure*. Here's a screen capture (note that the orientation of the bottom plot is back to normal, but not the text.

[image: Matlab fig]

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in R2015a.

Comment: I have R2014a and can't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @CapeCode That was from a Windows machine. It doesn't do this in Linux (nor Mac, probably).

Comment: @bongbang yep I use R2013a on a mac and it works fine

Comment: Confirmed.  This appears on Windows (R2013a) but not Mac.  I have MATLAB installed on both platforms.

Comment: Not reproducible in 2012b Linux.  Maybe try saving the handle of the colorbar without reversing its direction, then reversing its direction at the end with set(h,'xdir','reverse')?